# PHP In Memory Classes or Variable

Tags: php

Hi is there anyway to store variable into memory until server restart or manually recreate the same variable using PHP.

Actually the problem is this I nee do have a router in my application which have several configuration to route the URLs on different APIs. I do not want to load my configuration each time a request lands so I am searching a way to keep the configuration data into memory until I manually recreate the same.

Please suggest if there is anyway to do this.

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: I think you need to better explain the problem you're trying to solve, what you've tried, what works, what doesn't work and where you're having trouble. Write it as though you're writing a requirements specification.

Comment: Hi Matt, I am wondering if there is anyway to do this, I have tried to build a singleton class for the same but unfortunately it is quite different towards my requirements. Please suggest if there is anyway to achieve this in PHP. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what "this" is.

Comment: "Storing a variable into memory until server restart" is not in the scope of PHP. PHP is server-side scripting, which is called when a script is "hit" (via the command line or from a user browsing the site). It is compartmentalized into view-states. Once the view is closed, the data no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

PHP stores all variables in memory until the process exits (if the variable is a global) or until the scope ends (if the variable is local).

I think where you're getting confused is that Apache (or whatever webserver you're using) runs continuously, but it only starts PHP for every request, so PHP is never running continuously.

To store things across different requests, you'll need to use external persistence.  You can do this with PHP sessions, a database, flat files, etc. but none of these will store the data in memory.

Even though it's external, you can use a caching server like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) to store data in memory continuously, and then use PHP to access it through the [`Memcached`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) class.

Comment: Hi drrcknlsn and Matt,
Thanks for your concern so I only have a caching solution in that case. Thanks Again.

Comment: Also, your server probably has a disk cache that puts into memory often requested files. So probably although you are saving the file to disk, it is read more often from memory than from disk.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós: +1 for disk cache reminder.  Also, most RDMS have in-memory tables that can be used, which I forgot to mention.